# python: Force aiohttp to not normalize url

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.7, aiohttp

I use aiohttp to send a request like so:

```
async with ClientSession() as session: 
      res = await session.get("http://0.0.0.0:8000/./")
```

When I start up a http server using python like so:

`python3 -m http.server`

I see that the path is normalized, i.e., the server gets the following request:
`GET / HTTP/1.1" 200`

How do I disable this normalization, to enforce a behavior like in urrlib, for example, where `urllib.request.urlopen("http://0.0.0.0:8000/./")` results in the following request:
`GET /./ HTTP/1.1`.

Answer (score 4):

`aiohttp` uses [yarl](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/whats_new_1_1.html#yarl-and-url-encoding) for URL processing.

> `session.get('http://example.com')` works as well as `session.get(yarl.URL('http://example.com'))`

You can disable URL encoding for [yarl.URL](https://yarl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#yarl.URL) with `encoded=True`, but you have to take care of URL correctness.

e.g.

```py
import asyncio
import yarl
import aiohttp

async def test():
    url = yarl.URL('https://stackoverflow.com/./', encoded=True)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, allow_redirects=False) as resp:
            print(resp.url)
asyncio.run(test())
```