# AIOHTTP replacing %3A with :

Tags: python, aiohttp

```py
import yarl
async with cs.get(yarl.URL(f"https://ipqualityscore.com/api/json/url/{self.token}/{url}",encoded=True)) as r:
```

Hello, i'm having this issue where AIOHTTP is converting characters like `%3A` to the original `:`. i need to use the %3A version in the API req, if not, it raises 404

#### My code:

```py
for link in results:
    url = urllib.parse.quote(link, safe = '')
    print(url)
    ## ^^ 1st ^^

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:

        print(f"https://ipqualityscore.com/api/json/url/{self.token}/{url}")
        ## ^^ 2nd ^^

        async with cs.get(f"https://ipqualityscore.com/api/json/url/{self.token}/{url}") as r:
            text = await r.json()
            print(text)
```

#### URL it should've used:

```
https://ipqualityscore.com/api/json/url/PRIVATE_TOKEN/https%3A%2F%2Fstreancommunuty.ru%2Ftradoffer%2Fnew%2F%3Fpartner%3D1284276379%26token%3DiMDdLkoe
```

#### error raised (and url used):

```
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ContentTypeError: 0, message='Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: text/html; charset=utf-8', url=URL('https://ipqualityscore.com/api/json/url/PRIVATE_TOKEN/https:%2F%2Fstreancommunuty.ru%2Ftradoffer%2Fnew%2F%3Fpartner=1284276379&token=iMDdLkoe')
```

Comment: aalways put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not comment).

Comment: first you could check `print( url )` which you get from `urllib.parse.quote()`. If you get it with `:` then you can manually replace it with `%3A` - `url = url.replace(':', "%3A")`

Comment: eventually you may try to quote `"%3A"` or convert manually to `%253A`

Comment: What is `cs` in the third use of the URL? It seems like the error is coming from its `get` method, which for some reason is partially unquoting the quoted URL you gave it.

Comment: @Blckknght `cs` is from `async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, are you *sure* this is what you want to do? I ask because while `:` is a reserved character in URLs, it is not used as a delimiter in the *path* component of a URL, and so whether or not it is percent-encoded it should mean the exact same thing to the web server. Are you certain that whether the `:` is percent-encoded is the only thing causing your problem? That said, it's possible this particular web server isn't following the RFC properly, in which case it might be you need to work around it.

If it *is* what you want to do, I think you need to [prevent aiohttp from normalizing the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61140190/python-force-aiohttp-to-not-normalize-url). From the answer to that question, it sounds like you could do something like this:

```
import yarl

...

ipqs_url = yarl.URL(
    f"https://ipqualityscore.com/api/json/url/{self.token}/{url}",
    encoded=True)
await ctx.send(ipqs_url)
```

Similarly, you can pass a yarl.URL object to cs.get.

Comment: problem is that `url` has to be used in `cs.get(...)`, not `ctx.send(...)` - and `cs.get(...)` makes all problem.

Comment: yes i'm 100% sure. This API checks URLs so i need to pass the URL encoded like that, if not, it raises 404
Also, thanks! it worked:
`async with cs.get(yarl.URL(f"https://ipqualityscore.com/api/json/url/{self.token}/{url}",encoded=True)) as r:`

Comment: @furas The session should equally be able to take a Yarl URL object.

Comment: now I see: I tested it without `encoded=True` and it wasn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code based on @Weeble answer.

It uses `yarl` with `encoded=True` to stop requoting `%3A` to `:`

```
import urllib.parse
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import yarl

import os
token = os.getenv('IPQUALITYSCORE_TOKEN')

link = 'https://streancommunuty.ru/tradoffer/new/?partner=1284276379&token=iMDdLkoe'

async def main(link):
    url = urllib.parse.quote(link, safe='')
    print('--- url ---')
    print(url)
    
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
        
        yarl_url = yarl.URL(f"https://ipqualityscore.com/api/json/url/{token}/{url}", encoded=True)
                            
        async with cs.get(yarl_url) as r:
            #print('--- text ---')
            #text = await r.text() 
            #print(text)
            print('--- data ---')
            data = await r.json()
            print(data)
            print('--- url ---')
            print(r.url)
            
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(link))
```

**EDIT:**

I found [Request url of client session gets malformed #3424](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3424) which shows that it uses module yarl` which automatically reqoute some chars. It is doing to help create correct URL but in your situation it makes only problem. It may need to change source code to stop it.

Below is old version which doesn't resolve all problems.

---

**OLD:** (it doesn't resolve main problem)

Code doesn't raise error if I quote `link` two times

```
url = urllib.parse.quote(link, safe='')  # first time
url = urllib.parse.quote(url)            # second time
```

but I don't have `TOKEN` so I get message `Invalid or unauthorized key` from server and I can't check if this resolves all problems.

---

Minimal working code for test.

```
import urllib.parse
import aiohttp
import asyncio

token = 'PRIVATE_TOKEN'
link = 'https://streancommunuty.ru/tradoffer/new/?partner=1284276379&token=iMDdLkoe'

async def main(link):
    url = urllib.parse.quote(link, safe='')
    url = urllib.parse.quote(url)
    print('--- url ---')
    print(url)
    
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
    
        async with cs.get(f"https://ipqualityscore.com/api/json/url/{token}/{url}") as r:
            #print('--- text ---')
            #text = await r.text()
            #print(text)
            data = await r.json()
            print('--- data ---')
            print(data)
            
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(link))
```

Result:

```
--- url ---
https%253A%252F%252Fstreancommunuty.ru%252Ftradoffer%252Fnew%252F%253Fpartner%253D1284276379%2526token%253DiMDdLkoe
--- data ---
{'success': False, 'message': 'Invalid or unauthorized key. Please check the API key and try again.', 'request_id': '4DqddqGpINmFBAI'}
```

Comment: I don't think double escaping is the right thing to do. It will make any `:` character go away, but is *also* going to be double escaping everything else. All the `%XY` escapes are going to turn into `%25XY` as the `%` from the first escape gets escaped itself the second time around.

Comment: @Blckknght yes, it may not work but I don't have `TOKEN` to test it. At this moment  I create account on this portal to see if it get it as correct data. And maybe it will need to dig in source code of `aiohttp` to resolve this problem.

Comment: Sorry, this double thingy didn't work :( it raised HTTP error 503

Comment: @LeoCx1000 yes, I created account to test it and it seems it needs to change something directly in source code to skip it. Base on [Request url of client session gets malformed #3424](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3424) it uses module `yarl` which automatically convert `%3A` to `:` to create correct URL but in your situation it only makes problem. And they don't want to change it - you would have to correct source code and send to authors and then they can change it in next version.